# SVG Circle Scaling

Tags: css, svg

I have a simple SVG circle:

```
<svg version="1.1"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:a="http://ns.adobe.com/AdobeSVGViewerExtensions/3.0/"
 x="0px" y="0px" width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 100 100" overflow="visible" enable-background="new 0 0 100 100"
 xml:space="preserve">
<circle fill="#6E6F6F" cx="50" cy="50" r="49"/>
</svg>
```

This image is being used as a background, and resized to 22px:

```
background: transparent url('++resource++svg/star_neg.svg') no-repeat 0 0 / 22px 22px;
```

When I view this in the browser, the right and bottom sides of the circle appear flat in Firefox (Chrome looks fine).  If I zoom in on Firefox, the circle appears complete as expected.  How can I fix this?

Comment: As a workaround, I can just resize the SVG itself to 22px, but it seems this shouldn't be necessary. Even with doing this, when I zoom in on Firefox, the sides display as flat at various zooms.

Comment: This seems like a Firefox bug. Maybe search for it here: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=ALL+svg+background+image
My guess is that FF starts out trying to tile the image, computes the tile spacing slightly wrong, and then crops it to get a non-tiled version. Then you see the top and left sides of the circle repeated overlapping the bottom and right sides, making them look "flat". Indeed, the problem goes away if I make the dimensions of the SVG bigger without making the contents bigger (s/100/200/g; s/22/44/g).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a simple solution.  The div displaying the svg as the background should be larger than the SVG.  I had the box at 22px square, the same size I was setting the SVG.  To fix the issue, I displayed the box as 25px, with the background image centered instead of set in a corner.